# Selenium JavaScript - How to set test id in Jest test cases

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jestjs, testrail

I want to set an id to each test in Jest so that I can uniquely identify them.

It is something similar to `@TestParamters`/ `@Parameters` in TestNG.

Here - https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/results#addresult . If you look the end-point given here, it ask for `:test_id`.

So, I also want to give an id to each of my test cases and fetch that id in TestRail.

Answer (score 1):

Check [@jest-reporters/testrail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jest-reporters/testrail) plugin. It is a TestRail module for Jest. Helps to create test runs on TestRail for multiple suites and send results.

First, install the plugin

```
npm i @jest-reporters/testrail
```

Second, update `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  reporters: [
    ["testrail", {
      project_id: "1"
    }]
  ]
};
```

Third, in your test case files

```js
// "1:" this is Suite ID from Test Rail (Will work only for top)
describe("TestRail[1] Suite", () => {
  // "11:" this is Case ID from Test Rail
  it("TestRail[11] Test success", async() => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });

  it("TestRail[12] Test fail", async() => {
    expect(1).toBe(0);
  });

  xit("TestRail[13] Test skip", async() => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

The Suite ID from TestRail must be added to the start of top describe() description, ID should be in TestRail[ID].

The Case ID from TestRail must be added to the start of each it() description, ID should be in TestRail[ID].